# GDP per capita growth of Asia

Tags: national-income

[image]

This graph shows that South Korea, Malaysia, China, India, Pakistan, Bangladesh started around the 1970s. Income of South Koreans rocketed while Malaysia and China seem like they couldn't live up to their potential, and Indo-Pak-Bangla are sitting at the bottom with no visible change.

What is the basic problem of 3rd group I am talking about?

Comment: I'm not sure what's the basis of comparison here but two things come to mind 1. comparing GDP per capita in current USD is a precarious way of making judgements and comparisons between countries and across time (perhaps you need some measure of income expressed in ppp terms or [something](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geary%E2%80%93Khamis_dollar) like that; perhaps [this](http://cid.econ.ucdavis.edu/pwt.html) is helpful) 2. the countries you identify as peculiar in the provided context share a history of territorial disputes; also the former two are nuclear powers

Comment: It would be interesting to compare the population growth across those countries, I would guess that differences in growth rates might also contribute